# How to pick just the phone number from Phone book with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I know the intent for getting phone number

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CONTACT_NUMBER);
```

But I don't know how to get the phone number without requesting the contact read permission in onActivityResult().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing your code with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == GET_CONTACT_NUMBER) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

            // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
            // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
            // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
            // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
            // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

            // Do something with the phone number...
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: Before Android 2.3 (API level 9), performing a query on the
>   Contacts Provider (like the one shown above) requires that your app
>   declare the READ_CONTACTS permission (see Security and Permissions).
>   However, beginning with Android 2.3, the Contacts/People app grants
>   your app a temporary permission to read from the Contacts Provider
>   when it returns you a result. The temporary permission applies only to
>   the specific contact requested, so you cannot query a contact other
>   than the one specified by the intent's Uri, unless you do declare the
>   READ_CONTACTS permission.

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html